# Best way to pass a single word from a sentence in a webpage when its clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, web

Say, I have:

```
<p> This is a sentence </p>
```

And when a user clicks on words in the sentence (this, is, a, sentence), the web page will know that specific word is clicked. Is there something in js or the jQuery library for that?

I want to do that for my project in Django so that when they click on a word, I know which word in the sentence is clicked (not the whole sentence itself).

I only have 2 ideas for that:

1. Split the sentence into different elements so that it separates words when its clicked using javascript and getElementByID
             OR
2. Similar to #1 but I just use the anchor tag and pass the link and the value of the link in the same form so that I know which word in the sentence is passed () I'm guessing there's something wrong with this too.

Is there any better way? Or what is the best way?

Comment: You'd have to wrap each "clickable" word or words in their own elements to detect that.

Comment: I'd go with option #2 where I'd wrap all words as a link <a>...</a>. And simply pass along the word in the url like page.html?word=This

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We did this once, it was a really nasty thing to do on a whole document, but for a paragraph it wasn't bad.

Take the text node, split it on white space.  Then, wrap each word in a span and put it back into the document.

Attach a listener to the PARENT NODE and use delegation to figure out which span was clicked on.

Comment: ok, im probably gonna try to do that. sorry, i don't understand the last statement though. not familiar with jquery or all web material in general

Comment: Personal opinion -- best thing you can do is stay unfamiliar with jQuery.

That aside, you can read this, it will help out a bit.

http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate

Answer (score 2):

I think using multiple elements is the most standad compliant way, however...

...using a monospace font like courier, where you can preditc the width of each letter due to the font's monospaced nature, you should be able to track the x position of the mouse in the sentence.

You can use pageX to get the mouse X coordinates. Its client.x in IE.

```
  var properMethod = event.clientX || event.pageX;//This should select only the available non null property for the browsers
```

Comment: haha i thought about looking at the length of text too but i didnt wanna do that.

Answer (score 1):

I would go like that:

**html:**

```
<span>hello</span><span>world</span>
```

**jquery:**

```
$("span").click(function() {
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bAFG6/)

You need to replace the html using javascripts `.replace(regex, changedStuff)` to create clickable events for each of the words.

```
$('p').html(function(i, old) {
    return old.replace(/\b(\w+?)\b/g, '<span class="clickable">$1</span>')
}).click(function(e) { 
    alert(e.target.innerHTML);
});
```

Right now the html shows up if you click between words, but you get the idea.

Comment: sorry if this is a stupid question, i didnt learn jquery yet. so is that also doing the same thing as wrapping everything with span and applying onclick to all of those?

Comment: Yes, but this code does it automatically. Look at the jsFiddle demo

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't want to wrap every word in a tag beforehand, you could try doing it after the click. If you had separate paragraphs, you would only need to convert the one that the user clicked within.

For example (http://jsfiddle.net/scovetta/TU9rs/1/)

```
$('#paragraph').live('click', function($evt) {
    var original_text = $(this).text();
    var word_list = $(this).text().split(' ');      
    var word_html = '';

    // Convert each word to an individual span
    $.each(word_list, function(_, word) {
        word_html += '<span class="word">' + word + '</span> ';
    });

    // Replace original paragraph with the spans
    $(this).text('').html(word_html);

    // Search through each span for one in the right spot
    $('#paragraph .word').each(function(_, elt) {
        var rect = elt.getBoundingClientRect();
        if ($evt.pageX >= rect.left &&
                $evt.pageY >= rect.top &&
                $evt.pageX <= rect.right &&
                $evt.pageY <= rect.bottom) {
            alert('You clicked on the word: ' + $(elt).text());
            return;
        }
    });

    // Clean up after ourselves
    $(this).html('').text(original_text);
});
```

​​​​​​​​​​

Answer (score 0):

This attaches click events to all words in a specified selector. If that selector has any other child elements it skips it.

jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/bAExr/

jQuery

```
$('p').each(function(){

    var $this = $(this);

    if($this.children().length) return;    

    $this.html(function(i, old) {
        return old.replace(/\b(\w+?)\b/g, '<span>$1</span>')
    });

    $this.children().click(function(e) { 
        alert(e.target.innerHTML);
    });

});
```

​